# It's related to \noalign related error?

Tags: tables

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \penalty \@M \futurelet \@let@token \LT@@h...
l.836 \hline
```

Can anyone say what could be the possible source of error?

Comment: could you give us a minimal code, which results in this error? It is hard for us to guess what you are doing.

Comment: If you are inside a `longtable`, you may want to add `\tabularnewline` behind the `\caption{}`

Comment: The possible source of this error is that something is wrong inside a table. But without having a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) there is no way we can guess what is wrong.

Comment: @samcarter: a minimal *non*working example, I'd say :o)

Comment: Perhaps `\multicolumn` is not the first content in a cell?

Answer (score 2):

If you put `\hline` *anywhere* where it is not allowed, you will get this error, it has to be after `\begin{tabular}{ccc}` (or similar environments) or after `\\` (or `\tabularnewline`, `\endhead`, etc) (in a tabular or similar environment}.

If the code immediately before `\hline` is not one of those forms, then you will get the error that you show.